# Discerne between draw time and swap wait

Tags: opengl, timing

I have some routines that draw a scene, then I swap the buffers, and since I have swap wait set to 1, the call could block waiting for vertical synch.

Is it possible to measure how much time is spent in drawing the scene, and how much in waiting for the vertical sync? I tried to do the following:

```
start = clock();
drawstuff();
glFinish();
end = clock();
SwapBuffers();
swapend = clock();
```

but it doesn't seem to work, at least with my hardware and driver, because `end` and `swapend` are always the same.

Comment: I've been trying pretty much the same things, and I got different results with different graphic cards models (especially with different brands - I got an ATI HD 4250M, an ATI HD 4650, a Nvidia GT 640 and a Nvidia GTX 680). The conclusion I got was that this is implementation dependent, or that there is no way to get these times without an especific solution to retrieve the times straight from the driver.

Comment: do you get `swapend == end` too?

Comment: Yes, on 4250M. The GT 640 I got different values. The others I can't remenber right now, since they are higher end cards and I don't really pay too much attention to the benchmarks on them.

Comment: using `clock()` for such things is not really a good idea. The resolution is very bad, and CPU time is not a good indicator to measure calls which might block - as they don't have to use busy waiting. On modern implementations, there is a high chance the `SwapBuffers()` will not block even in a double-buffered (as opposed to tripe-buffered) setup, any new issued drawing commands will effectifely have to wait for the swap, but the client can go on asynchronously.

Comment: *"there is no way to get these times without an especific solution to retrieve the times straight from the driver."* You can use Timer Query Objects in a modern OpenGL implementation to time the duration of a sequence of commands. I use them to time individual tasks in my pipeline (e.g. G-Buffer creation, shadow map creation, lighting, HDR post-process, MSAA resolve, GUI, buffer swap, etc.), but you could use 1 timer query for your entire frame if you wanted. You will want to limit the query interval to every couple of frames or querying the timer itself will become the largest bottleneck :)

Comment: Just to add this, [`glBeginQuery`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBeginQuery.xml) is limited to running one query of each type at once. Using [`glQueryCounter`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glQueryCounter.xml), you can request as many timestamps as you want and calculate the difference yourself. In any case you'll want to average over a few frames to get an accurate result.

Comment: I've just tested my code under Windows, and got different results for the same graphic card (GT 640), but different platform. The swap buffer operation is first handled by the WGL (on Windows) or the XGL (on X11), before being sent to the driver. I think more than just a driver behavior, it is also WM dependent.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Didn't know OpenGL has this feature. I'll try to implement it in my code base. Thank you!

Comment: I wonder why this is not possible. It seems to me, and I'm a naive programmer, that it is something easy to implement, but would really help, if you want to waste as little as possible time in waiting for a swap, by guessing when that would happen, and start drawing accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your clocks resolution is not enough. Use `std::chrono`, `boost::chrono`, or platform-specific clocks.

Example ([ideone](http://ideone.com/w4aqHi)):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::nanoseconds;
using std::chrono::microseconds;

typedef  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock myclock;
typedef myclock::time_point time_point;
typedef myclock::duration duration;

auto time_to_wait = microseconds(1000);

inline void doStuff()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(time_to_wait);
}

int main() 
{
    time_point start, end;
    start = myclock::now();
    doStuff();
    end = myclock::now();

    auto elapsed =  duration_cast<microseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << elapsed .count() << " microseconds elapsed\n";
}
```

Notes:

1. Better use profiler.
2. Even better use graphics profiler.
3. You will get very different results on different platforms, different vendors and even drivers versions. Does it really make any sense to measure?
4. You don't really need to call `glFinish()`
5. If you're on Windows and MSVC compiler, don't use `std::chrono`. Use `boost::chrono` or `QueryPerformanceCounter` instead.
6. AFAIK Swap blocking depends on driver implementation. Typically it is non-blocking, due to vendors implement it in threaded way. If you're in doubt, it is always good idea to move your calculations (but not rendering) to separate thread.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, `clock()` was a sort of pseudocode, of course I use something that givesa resolutino in nanoseconds